# How to get size of each element in array of char arrays

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof, qsort

I have a quick question, if I have an array of character strings like this:

`char *array[3] = {"hello","hi","goodbye"};`

How do I get the size of each element in the array? I am trying to do a qsort function but qsorts' third argument requires the size in bytes of each element in the array. Thanks

Comment: The title is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want the size (i.e. length) of the strings if you're using qsort.  You want the size of the the array elements.  So that would be `sizeof(char *)`.

Answer (score 4):

The size you're looking for is `sizeof(char *)`, because your array members are just pointers to character arrays.

*edit:* ... and this is a duplicate already

Answer (score 1):

This array

```
char *array[3] = {"hello","hi","goodbye"};
```

is an array of pointers that is its elements have type `char *` and the size `sizeof( char * )`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmp( const void *lhs, const void *rhs )
{
    const char **a = ( const char ** )lhs;
    const char **b = ( const char ** )rhs;

    return strcmp( *a, *b );
}

int main( void )
{
    char *array[3] = { "hello", "hi", "goodbye" };
    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) puts( array[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    qsort( array, N, sizeof( char * ), cmp );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) puts( array[i] );
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

The program output is

```
hello
hi
goodbye

goodbye
hello
hi
```

If you like pointers or asterisks then you may write the call of qsort even the following way :)

```
    qsort( array, N, sizeof( char * ), *****cmp );
```